# Is it possible to find all md5 hashes in file and save it to another file?

Tags: python, hash, extract, md5

I have a txt file (a few gigabytes size!) which i want to extract md5 hashes from. This would be easy task for me but... amount of spaces in every line between words are irregular. For example:

NUMBER (a few spaces) LOGIN (a few spaces) MAIL (a few spaces) MD5 HASH (a few spaces) DATE
(a few spaces) SOME USELESS CHARACTERS.

All data after md5 is useless.
I'd like to extract all md5 hashes from this file and only md5. I do not need any other data. This would be an easy task if there would be a regular amount of spaces between logins, mails and hashes but... I am not enough experiences. Amount of spaces may vary betweend data.

Thanks for all help.

So far i managed to change content of file located
[here (md5hashes.txt)](http://mbaraniecki.pl/files/lines.txt)
to [this format (lines.txt)](http://mbaraniecki.pl/files/md5hashes.txt) using this code:

```
import io
import re

errors = 0

#name of file to store addresses
file_to_save = open("md5hashes.txt", 'w') # this file contains md5 hashes with other useless data
file_to_read = "lines.txt" #and there we will store only md5

print(f"Hello. Opening {file_to_read}")


with io.open(file_to_read, mode='r', encoding='utf8') as file_to_open:
data = file_to_open.readlines()

for data_in_file in data:
    file_to_save.write(str(data_in_file.split()))

file_to_open.close()
file_to_save.close()
print("All files closed.")
```

I thought this will remove spaces and will ease parsing file to remove other useless data. But no.

Any ideas?

Maybe a better idea would be to check every string if it has exactly 32 chars long and contains only a-f letters and 0-9 digits, and extract it to another file?

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> 'NUMBER  LOGIN     MAIL  MD5_HASH  DATE      SOME_USELESS_CHARACTERS'.split()
    ['NUMBER', 'LOGIN', 'MAIL', 'MD5_HASH', 'DATE', 'SOME_USELESS_CHARACTERS']
```

[str.split()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split), i.e. without any argument will treat consecutive white-spaces as one

EDIT:
With the data from [lines.txt](http://mbaraniecki.pl/files/lines.txt):

```
with open('lines.txt') as f:
    hashes = [line.split()[3] for line in f]

print(hashes)
```

output

```
['e2a18210956d33cd2f636d2cd9286e4a', '4f1d414c5f6c91858a5a9f997b56194a', '99d6341dbd215172886e40227c7960db', 'fa077d39cb67070d255b200196bfc7e6', '5469aba04997b10ce9cee08498eb0368', '9c8be11d1d1b76555dcbac30d6c6b19b', '067c10d420547bf07d40bc096ad12c74', 'c6983b366e2ff8a0ab159d6778cff745', '9f22f8432cf7554cc52706164a1d4191', '0a23eb155ee725dd5c4a52b34d91073d', 'a700028489912c64da295a8466cf8e5b', 'e6ac227d436afadddb8dab18a49d8051', 'b9be9adee29895765f1a48b0ea7d3d82', '8d84ed9be2bfb96b0332beb1c4d0c577', '46470f42630e4a603383a58b8ae4a1f7', '418b45086b2a216939705d36c0acf989', '56289f28e8816d2272f6452e7313a76f', '2004-09-14', 'acfda40bb16465ffc42a2c573f8a8d0d', '3dc5a9c8f6f3822de0634a4f5cd4ae8c', '25d55ad283aa400af464c76d713c07ad', 'e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e', 'da2092eb7a8905c8f711650eb43ddba8', '1de164dbf6b484df90bfda65e2610dba', 'f87462bc136a9dbe6aa3ad802b45ecd2', '6e207e6c794467cb361b7b0aa32a7123', '37a58dd2291bb48bd2746b5aeb1c2999', '82203b49f312584c5fc6aa27954bb416', '20c9926ade8211bfac99a3b01852d32d', '1c91b775b4ef959426d78eacca908690', '3c61262142f9e33fd7ff96811c469c0f', '72acde4a88378f62cf580ed7024d7a0d', '6b1d24ff83a319070db95c6c84b9be31', '02051eaad6027fc861248a2f2f314bb3', '7d550855dcfa16e1af386b4fab05bc97', '64cb8e79efcab677bce933f037ee930e', 'fdcca1ac3b4e09d5be64c0ce93f6a894', 'fb9cf8cda3655922c953ee252c4ea92b', 'de0dfe3265f63b0fdcc3067e3b0ecc60']
```

You will notice there is inconsistency in your data - a missing e-mail on line 18. As a result, the element at index 3 is the date, not the hash. It's up to you to tell if this is glitch in the sample data (i.e. you deleted it when you anonymize the data) or it's indeed problem with data

Comment: I added code what i tried to do. If you could take a look at the content of the post... ;)

Comment: check my edited answer